# accessing a local file (Java URL)

Tags: java, url, io, urlconnection

I'm trying to open a stream to a file on my PC and I'm trying to do it via URL (I know,It's just for leraning purposes)
this is what I'm doing:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class URLTyper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream in=null;
        try {
            URL url=new URL("file://127.0.0.1/c:/haxlogs.txt");
//          in=url.openStream();
            URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            in=conn.getInputStream();
            while (true) {
                int read=in.read();
                if (read==-1) break;
                System.out.write(read);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e){
            System.out.println("timed out");
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("URL not valid");
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("unable to get data");
        }
    }

}
```

It exits throwing an IOException ("unable to access data").. why is it not working? shouldn't it get to the file like an ordinary InputStream?
thanks

Comment: your `url` is invalid...

Comment: try `file:///c:/haxlogs.txt` ?

Comment: The `file` protocol doesn't require a `host` portion. It implies localhost

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi please can you provide a valid url for the resource?

Comment: thanks @BrettWalker, that explained it, thank you!

Comment: It depends, if you are getting the resources from the server, you could use:
`127.0.0.1/ProjectName/haxlogs.txt` but you are using the file from the local file system so you better use: `file:///c:/haxlogs.txt`.